# How to process only the failed files in for each activity when the master pipeline is retriggered in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

There are two pipelines Master and child.
In the child pipeline there is a foreach activity which takes files as input and process them in parallel.
For instance, there are 4 files , in which 2 files are successfully processed and loaded the data into a table. Then, 3rd file processing is failed and 4th file  processing is successful. Now, when I retrigger the Master pipeline I only want the 3rd file to be processed, not all the 4 files.
How can we achieve this.

I have tried below.

```
To move/delete the file once the processing is completed
```

But as per the requirement, I should not move/delete the file. Could someone please assist.

Comment: Before foreach activity, is there a File Name array? Can we filter the array if there is already data in same name tables?

Comment: Yes,we have a filename array. Here we are actually loading all the processed files data into a single table. In such cases, how can we handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a test and succefuly achieve that. My overall idea is: use the Lookup activity to extract the copied file names array from the sql table, and then do a Filter operation with the source file names array. If the file name already exists in the sql table, the file copy activity will not be performed. It needs us to add file name to the sql table in Copy activity via **Aditional columns**.
[image]
In my sql  table, it looks like as follows:
[image]

1. I declared 3 variables. `arr1` Array type variable stores source file names. `filterArray` Array type variable stores copied file names array from the sql table.
   [image]
2. At lookup activity, we can use this query `select distinct FileName from  [dbo].[emp]` to get copied file names array from the sql table.
   [image]
3. Assign the value to the variable `filterArray`.
   [image]
4. I set the default value `["emp.csv","emp2.csv","emp3.csv","emp4.csv"]` as source file names to the variable `arr1`.
   [image]
5. At Foreah acivity, we can foreach the variable `arr1`.
   [image]
6. Inside Foreach activity, assign the value `@item()` to the variable `arrItem`.
   [image]
7. Then do Filter operation. Items: `@variables('filterArr')`,  Condition: `@contains(item().FileName,variables('arrItem'))`, This `item()` here represents each element in the `filterArray` array.
   [image]
8. At If condition activity, use `@empty(activity('Filter1').output.Value)` to determine whether this file has been copied.
   [image]
9. In Ture activity, key in dynamic content `@item()`, this represents the name of the file to be copied.
   [image]

That's all.

Comment: Thank you. The above solution is useful.